# Which is a better practice for if-else condition?

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization

Which one of these two options are better?

```
if(obj.getType!=null && obj.getData()!=null)
{
  // Do something
}
elseif(obj.getData==null)
{
  // Do other thing
}

*OR*

if(obj.getType!=null)
{  
  if(obj.getData!=null)
  {
    // Do something
  }
  else
 {
   // Do other thing
 }
}
```

The major point of doubt is why to do null check for getData twice in the first way? The second option does it only once.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. Personally, the complexity of the requirements dictate which style I might use

Comment: The second one seems better to me as it is more readable and will be more easily maintainable. But as MadProgramer said, it is a matter of opinion.

Comment: The two if-else statements have different behaviour. When obj.getType==null and obj.getData==null.

Comment: Well, since the first one doesn't compile, I'd go with the second one...

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference between the two options. In the first option, the part `elseif(obj.getData==null)` will be executed whether `object.getType` is null or not. But, in the second option, the block will be executed only if `object.getType` is not null. So, I think it depends upon your requirement.

Comment: Nice catch +1, and yes, it definitely depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Agreed. But if we look just into performance sake, which one would be better?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need.

Consider you have a requirement that stipulates you collect 2 data points that represent values that are greater than 0, and you have to give feedback on if and which values are invalid.

```
public Data(int x, int y) 
{
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0) { 
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid data provided, got (x: %d, y:%d)", x, y); 
    }
}
```

Note that checking for null and then checking for a condition is a fairly normal pattern called a null guard.

```
public void setValue(SomeValue o) { 
    if (o == null || o.Value <= 0) { 
        // code to handle bad value
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you have a set of conditions that need to be checked in order, and fail out if one isn't met, you can ([not recommended](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/)) use chained `if`s like you have:

```
public void someOperation() 
{ 
    if (condition) 
    { 
        if (condition2) 
        {
            if (condition3) 
            { 
                // operation here
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Note that although you don't explicitly mention something other than control statements, if you have a situation similar to the preceeding example, I would *strongly* recommend refactoring the condition checks by inverting them, and if the checks are complicated, refactor them out to methods returning `boolean`.

```
public void someOperation() 
{ 
    if (!condition) 
    {
        // code to fail out
    }

    if (!condition2) 
    {
        // code to fail out
    }

    if (!complexCondition())
    {
        // code to fail out
    }

    // operation here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But if we look just into performance sake, which one would be better?

Comment: @Vwin, http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @jdphenix Your guardIf() method's condition are wrong. It should be x<=0 and y and z for second and third condition. (Although the performance would not be affected)

Comment: @hk6279 Indeed, nice catch :)

Comment: Sorry, but your benchmark results are worthless. See e.g. [here](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks). Btw., any Java benchmark taking less than a second is crap (google for warm-up).

Answer (score 2):

Null check for getData isn't *always* done twice in the first example. It is only ensured to get done no matter what. The `&&` operator checks if left condition is true `(if obj.getType != null)`, and only if it is, does it proceed on with checking the second one `(if obj.getData() != null)`. `&&` and `||` are lazy operators. If they can determine the value of whole boolean statement after checking the first condition, then they do not go onto examining the others - unlike `&` or `|`.

Second version doesn't ever check for `obj.getData` value unless the outer condition is met. If it is not, you never get to reach the second block.