# Performance of behaviorally identical conditional checks

Tags: java, performance, jit

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234401/which-is-a-better-practice-for-if-else-condition/25234523) and noticed something that intrigued me while running the code for it. Part of the question was about the performance of various styles of identical conditional checks, for example:

```
if (x > 0) { 
    if (y > 0) { 
        if (z > 0) { 
            if (complexCondition()) { 
                 noOp();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

versus

```
if (x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && complexCondition()) { 
     noOp();
}
```

I wrote a program that times how long a certain number of iterations takes to execute, and the results are what I don't understand.

Here's the output of my program on my machine (Win 8.1 64-bit, javac 1.8.0_11 (Oracle), java 1.0.0_11 (Java SE, Oracle). I've ran each trial multiple times and they yield repeatable results.

```
x = 9, y = 2, z = 8, countTrials = 1, iterationsPerTrial = 2736000
Method        Average Runtime(ns)
guardIf()     5746173
multipleIf()  4868180
chainedIf()   9316172

x = 9, y = 2, z = 8, countTrials = 100, iterationsPerTrial = 2736000
guardIf()     1642750
multipleIf()  1121897
chainedIf()   1739522

x = -1, y = 2, z = 8, countTrials = 1, iterationsPerTrial = 2736000 // I expect shorter results with x = -1, because they all short curcuit
guardIf()     9245313
multipleIf()  8728608
chainedIf()   11718332

x = -1, y = 2, z = 8, countTrials = 100, iterationsPerTrial = 2736000 
guardIf()     1754279
multipleIf()  1611278
chainedIf()   4947295
```

Millisecond measurements (implemented with `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch`)

```
x = 9, y = 2, z = 8, countTrials = 1, iterationsPerTrial = Integer.MAX_VALUE
Method        Average Runtime(ms)
guardIf()     1664
multipleIf()  1095
chainedIf()   1654

x = -1, y = 2, z = 8, countTrials = 1, iterationsPerTrial = Integer.MAX_VALUE
Method        Average Runtime(ms)
guardIf()     4886
multipleIf()  4926
chainedIf()   4862

x = 9, y = 2, z = 8, countTrials = 10, iterationsPerTrial = Integer.MAX_VALUE
Method        Average Runtime(ms)
guardIf()     1673
multipleIf()  1108
chainedIf()   1682

x = -1, y = 2, z = 8, countTrials = 10, iterationsPerTrial = Integer.MAX_VALUE
Method        Average Runtime(ms)
guardIf()     4364
multipleIf()  4363
chainedIf()   4877
```

**Why do runs of all methods takes longer (in the case of `chainIf`, almost 300% more time) when the values they are checking allow them all to short curcuit?**

I've stepped through them all with the debugger, and they do infact short curcuit (as I'd expect). I've examined the bytecode and `chainedIf()` and `multipleIf()` are exactly identical. I'm stumped and curious.

I'm not sure if there's some flaw in the way I'm performing my measurement, so I've included my program below.

*Program source*

```
class TrialResult {
    public long GuardIf = 0; 
    public long MultipleIf = 0; 
    public long ChainedIf = 0; 

    public TrialResult(long guardIf, long multipleIf, long chainedIf) { 
        this.GuardIf = guardIf; 
        this.MultipleIf = multipleIf; 
        this.ChainedIf = chainedIf; 
    }
}

public class Program {

    private int x; 
    private int y; 
    private int z; 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Program program = new Program(); 
        List<TrialResult> trials = new ArrayList<TrialResult>(); 
        int countTrials = 1; 

        for (int j = 0; j < countTrials; j++) {     
            long t0 = 0, t1 = 0; 

            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            for (long i = 0; i < 2073600; i++) { 
                program.chainedIf();
            }
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            long chainIf = t1 - t0;

            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            for (long i = 0; i < 2073600; i++) { 
                program.multipleIf();
            }

            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            long multipleIf = t1 - t0;

            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            for (long i = 0; i < 2073600; i++) { 
                program.guardIf();
            }
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            long guardIf = t1 - t0;
            System.out.printf("Trial %d completed\r\n", j+1);

            trials.add(new TrialResult(guardIf, multipleIf, chainIf)); 
        }

        long chainIf = 0, multipleIf = 0, guardIf = 0; 
        for (TrialResult r : trials) { 
            chainIf += r.ChainedIf; 
            multipleIf += r.MultipleIf; 
            guardIf += r.GuardIf; 
        }
        System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d", guardIf / trials.size(), multipleIf / trials.size(), chainIf / trials.size()); 
    }

    private Program() {
        x = 9; 
        y = 2; 
        z = 8; 
    }

    private void chainedIf() { 
        if (x > 0) { 
            if (y > 0) { 
                if (z > 0) { 
                    if (complexCondition()) { 
                         noOp();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void multipleIf() { 
        if (x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && complexCondition()) { 
             noOp();
        }
    }

    public void guardIf() { 
        if (x <= -1) { 
            return; 
        }

        if (y <= -1) { 
            return; 
        }

        if (z <= -1) { 
            return; 
        }

        if (!complexCondition()) { 
            return; 
        }

         noOp();
    }

    private boolean complexCondition() { 
        return (x > 0 && 
            y < x && 
            y + z > x
        );      
    }

    private void noOp() { 
        return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Microbenchmarks are almost completely meaningless because there is a JIT, and your clock accuracy is not nanosecond accurate. If the byte-code is the same then the JIT is the *only* answer I can think of.

Comment: In addition to JIT, this micro-benchmark may be affected by branch prediction.

Comment: I'd argue the documentation for `System.nanoTime()` is faulty, i.e. "_For example, to measure how long some code takes to execute:_". I'm going to revisit my benchmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do runs of all methods takes longer (in the case of chainIf, almost 300% more time) when the values they are checking allow them all to short curcuit?

Because your benchmark is faulty. Please read the answer to a similar question:
[Java loop gets slower after some runs / JIT's fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882946/java-loop-gets-slower-after-some-runs-jits-fault/24889503#24889503)