# Java Fibonacci - elapsedTime(); formula

Tags: java

I'm working on a small project for the fibonacci algorithm.

I'm using the following method to calculate the algorithm. Note that `elapsedTime()` returns a `double`.

```
public static void fibonacciSequence(long n1, long n2) {

    t0 = stopwatch.elapsedTime();
    System.out.print("index: " + index + " -> " + n1 + "\t");
    t1 = stopwatch.elapsedTime();
    lapTime = (1000 * t1 - 1000 * t0) / 1000;
    StdOut.println(" (" + lapTime + "\t " + t1 + ")");

    if (index == stoppingPoint) {
        return;
    }
    index++;
    fibonacciSequence(n2, n1 + n2);
}
```

Now don't pay too much attention about the algorithm itself - it gets fixed. I only don't understand the formula for lapTime. Why can't it be

```
lapTime = t1-t0;
```

Comment: What does elapsedTime() return---means which datatype and time in ms/ns or sec??? The answer is hidden in that!

Comment: You can use your formula. It's correct.

Comment: Perhaps it may have to do with casting from double to int?

Comment: I'm new to programming, but i found it's a return double second. In that way it makes sense to /1000 because most of the values are 0.001 - 0.005. Thanks !

Comment: @dz3k If it a `double` type, that is because you are using `double` types. A simpler alternative is to use `long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()`.  btw why are you timing how long the print statement takes?  You realise the calculation is less than 1/1000th the work that your method is doing.

Comment: Note: using the difference of elapse times, is the same as the difference of times.

Comment: @PeterLawrey For school I tried 2 methods to calculate the Fibonacci algorithm. It came down to having an old method that took hours to calculate a index of around >45. I used this timer to compare the time for both the methods to calculate the algorithm.

Comment: What is the datatype for `lapTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This belongs to [`Stopwatch`](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/Stopwatch.java.html) class from [Java Princeton Stdlib](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/). This class is meant to measure the time of the execution of an algorithm. The implementation goes like this (removed comments and such data):

```
public class Stopwatch { 

    private final long start;

    public Stopwatch() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } 

    public double elapsedTime() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return (now - start) / 1000.0;
    }
}
```

Since it uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` it will work with milliseconds. But the `elapsedTime` method already convert it back to seconds but as a `double`. So your current formula:

```
lapTime = (1000 * t1 - 1000 * t0) / 1000;
```

Is making sure to convert the data into a pure `double` operation. So, the formula can be rewritten as:

```
lapTime = t1 - t0;
```

With no problem.

Note that still **this is not the right way to measure time of execution for Java code**. You should use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) instead.

More info:

- [How do I measure time elapsed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1770010/1065197)

---

Going *deeper* to understand if there's no difference between these operations, let's create a basic test:

```
public class FormulaTest {
    static double formula1(double t0, double t1) {
        return (1000 * t1 - 1000 * t0) / 1000;
    }

    static double formula2(double t0, double t1) {
        return t1 - t0;
    }

    static void printResults(double t0, double t1) {
        System.out.println("t0: " + t0);
        System.out.println("t1: " + t1);
        System.out.println("Formula1: " + formula1(t0, t1));
        System.out.println("Formula2: " + formula1(t0, t1));
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        // your code goes here
        printResults(0, 10);
        printResults(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis());
        printResults(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis() + 142);
        printResults(1.7976931348623157e+300 - 5000, 1.7976931348623157e+300);
        printResults(
            109999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.0,
            119999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.0);
        printResults(
            10.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
            11.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999);
        printResults(
            823145321462149234.651985149616914621346234923149621346921394613293423951932415934159213226314,
            844329146321496321.532159341563149513495139159341593415793415431951349513891585443951391593151);
        printResults(
            82314532.1462149234651985149616914621346234923149621346921394613293423951932415934159213226314,
            84432914.6321496321532159341563149513495139159341593415793415431951349513891585443951391593151);
        printResults(1.7976931348623157e+307, 4.9e-323);
        printResults(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        printResults(Double.MIN_VALUE - 10, Double.MIN_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
t0: 0.0
t1: 10.0
Formula1: 10.0
Formula2: 10.0
---------------------------------------------------
t0: 1.410290897577E12
t1: 1.410290897577E12
Formula1: 0.0
Formula2: 0.0
---------------------------------------------------
t0: 1.410290897577E12
t1: 1.410290897719E12
Formula1: 142.0
Formula2: 142.0
---------------------------------------------------
t0: 1.7976931348623156E300
t1: 1.7976931348623156E300
Formula1: 0.0
Formula2: 0.0
---------------------------------------------------
t0: 1.1E71
t1: 1.2E71
Formula1: 9.999999999999985E69
Formula2: 9.999999999999985E69
---------------------------------------------------
t0: 11.0
t1: 12.0
Formula1: 1.0
Formula2: 1.0
---------------------------------------------------
t0: 8.2314532146214925E17
t1: 8.4432914632149632E17
Formula1: 2.1183824859347024E16
Formula2: 2.1183824859347024E16
---------------------------------------------------
t0: 8.231453214621492E7
t1: 8.443291463214964E7
Formula1: 2118382.4859347227
Formula2: 2118382.4859347227
---------------------------------------------------
t0: 1.7976931348623158E307
t1: 4.9E-323
Formula1: -Infinity
Formula2: -Infinity
---------------------------------------------------
t0: 1.7976931348623157E308
t1: 1.7976931348623157E308
Formula1: NaN
Formula2: NaN
---------------------------------------------------
t0: -10.0
t1: 4.9E-324
Formula1: 10.0
Formula2: 10.0
---------------------------------------------------
```

Not even at edge cases `Double.MAX_VALUE` and `Double.MIN_VALUE` are differences between the results of the formula. Even when the result is `-Infinity` or `NaN` (not a number).

In short: use the last formula:

```
lapTime = t1 - t0;
```

Comment: +0 "Is making sure to convert the data into a pure int operation." this is not converting the `double` into an `int` or a `long`

Comment: Even your answer is wrong,the datatype for t0 and t1 ca't be assumed `long`,unless OP clarifies! I have chnged my votes,a -1 to you!

Comment: You have demonstrated that `t0` and `t1` must be `double`, see  `double elapseTime()` not `long` and if it was `long` multiplying by 1000 wouldn't make any difference. As it is `double` doing `1000 * ` would still be a double.

Comment: Note: I suspect the original author may have intended that it "Is making sure to convert the data into a pure long operation" but is not actually doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you use for calculating the variable `lapTime` can be simplified, and you've posted the simplest representation it can have.

```
lapTime = (1000 * t1 - 1000 * t0) / 1000;
```

Can instead be :

```
lapTime = t1 - t0;
```

Which can be determined through simple algebra. It's even possible, given that `t1` and `t0` are `double` that the two expressions *could* result in a different value even if they mathematically equivalent. [See here](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

As far as the problem you're trying to solve, measuring the execution time of a Java program, [there be dragons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java). Here's my [own attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235950/performance-of-behaviorally-identical-conditional-checks) at measuring with a micro-benchmark, which I ultimately believe was a failure.

Comment: Your answer is correct but your explanation can be incorrect if some other datatypes are involved like int,double,etc. So,you shouldn't out points related to `simple algebra`! ALso,check my answer for more insight!

Comment: @shekharsuman As stated, without clarification on data types no answer can be 100% _absolutely positively correct_. Making points about fundamental mathematics is valid, especially with the behavior that comes with using floating-point values.

Comment: Actually,OP gave datatypes as of double type as return type of `elaapsedTime()` method! You must check comments beneath OP's question!

Comment: good point of editing question!Please modify your answer accordingly,I'll upvote your answer!

Comment: Please remove that point,related to floating point as time will be bounded and won't ever be something like `0.333...`... I already mentioned that your answer seems correct,but floating point condition doesn't suit this question.

Answer (score -1):

Well it *should* be.

```
(a * x - a * y) / a == (x - y) * a / a == x - y
```

In your case:

```
(1000 * t1 - 1000 * t0) / 1000 == (t1 - t0) * 1000 / 1000 == t1 - t0
```

So writing `lapTime = t1-t0` is a good idea as it makes the code easier to understand.

In addition, you also avoid risking overflowing `long` by not multiplying by `1000` any more.

Comment: Because the answer is not `synced` with question as well as the answer is a poor summary!!!

Comment: @JeanLogeart perhaps you could use `-` instead of `+` in your explanation.

Comment: @JeanLogeart-See Luiggi's answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey-i doubt how this answer was upvoted 3 times,check Luiggi's answer! I can't believe even you support this answer!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman Given Luggi's explanation is non-sense, I don't see how it got upvoted.

Comment: @PeterLawrey-SORRY,I downvoted his also,that's pure CRAP!!! But,neither is this OK, One can't assume t1 and t0 to be of long type unless OP clarifies! I can very well claim that program execution time can be of even int/double unless clarified!

Comment: When I try    lapTime = t1-t0; 

    StdOut.println(" (" + lapTime + "\t " + t1 + ")");

The decimals can be quite big for example (@ index 40 value is): 
0.5030000000000001

But if i use the formula:

0.504

Comment: @PeterLawrey-Kindly check my answer and place some comments if free to do so!